# Should I use "" (quotations) While defining variable? But With/Without Works

Tags: php

I have just started learning PHP, and here's my first doubt...

Both of these work:

```
<?php
$function1 = "Aahan";
print "Hi, $function1";
?>
```

and

```
<?php
$function2 = Aahan;
print "Hi, $function2";
?>
```

See the difference? In the second example I didnt use the "" (quotation marks) for the variable string. But it still works.

Also, the stupid author of the book (which I wont name), uses "" in some examples and doesnt use them in some, without explanation. So, what should I think? Either way is okay or what do you advise?

EDIT: Sorry guys, the author is a good one. I misunderstood this string `$x = 3;`, and started checking out the above examples. Just realized that constants don't need quotes. Sorry again.

**EDIT-2: it doesn't show me any error like you all have mentioned. How do I make it show the errors? or is it something wrong with my server itself? (I dont think so)**

Comment: Definitely use quotes.

Comment: Sounds like you should get a different book.

Comment: Are you sure the author isn't using a named constant in some examples?

Comment: Corrected. The author is a good one. He wasn't using quotes for contants. I wasn't just knowledgeable enough to understand. But since it's a complete beginner's book, he should have put in some explanation, which he didn't.

Comment: @Aahan A common beginners mistake. Even i had once confused the same in java. :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aahan,

```
$function1 = "Aahan";
```

Is the right method for php. Its a string of chareters. Refer to [php strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php).

Now when you do

```
$function2 = Aahan;
```

Php searches for a constant Aahan and when its not defined it treats it as a string. To explain further. Consider these:

```
$function1 = "Aahan Is My Name";
```

And

```
$function2 = Aahan Is My Name;
```

While the first one with " "(quotes) is right. The 2nd one gives you a syntax error.

This is the warning gernerated, unless you have turned it off

> Notice: Use of undefined constant Aahan - assumed 'Aahan'

**EDIT:** To turn on comprehensive [Error reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) Add the following code to the first line of your code.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Comment: it doesn't show me any error like others and you have mentioned. How do I make it show the errors? I am just beginning...

Comment: @Aahan Add error reporting option using the php's function. Check out my edit to the answer. If you follow the link you will find a more comprehensiveness discussion in the official php page. This site is where you have to refer to usually for any php's syntax and semantics.

Answer (score 10):

**Use the first!!**

In PHP, strings without quotes constitute a [constant](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.syntax.php).  If no existing constant is found, the value produced is the name itself, which is why the second "works".

The second produces an unsightly E_NOTICE as well:

> Notice: Use of undefined constant Aahan - assumed 'Aahan' in /test.php on line 2

Comment: Does "constant" mean a number (integer/real)?

Comment: No, it means simple data types (number/boolean/string).  From the link: "Only scalar data (boolean, integer, float and string) can be contained in constants."

Comment: @Aahan: No, a constant means, that the value is constant over the whole application/request livetime --> the value of a constant can't be changed only assigned at the beginning.

Answer (score 4):

The second one actually should be issuing a warning, "**UNDEFINED CONSTANT Aahan ASSUMING 'Aahan'**". Always quote to avoid this.

Also, make sure your error reporting is set to max while developing.

Answer (score 4):

Without quotes is incorrect, and if you have notices enabled:

***Notice: Use of undefined constant Aahan - assumed 'Aahan' in test.php on line xx***

What its telling you is that while the code isn't valid, PHP is clever enough to make an assumption to allow your code to execute and not terminate.  You should avoid this sort of thing though as PHP's assumption of what the value of 'Aahan' is may not be correct.  In this case, its assuming it is a constant, and its value is 'Aahan'.

To do that correctly would be this:

```
define("Aahan","Aahan");
echo Aahan;
```

Results in

```
Aahan
```

And no errors - although its common practice for a constant to be defined with its name in block capitals.  Its not required, but it makes things easier to read.

If you're defining a string in a variable, use quotes.  If you're defining a number, don't.

Valid code:

```
$myVariable = "Hello World"; //this is a string
$myVariable = 3.42; //this would set $myVariable to a numeric value.
$myVariable = HELLO_WORLD; //this would set $myVariable to the value of constant HELLO_WORLD
```

In the third case, if you hadn't defined HELLO_WORLD - you'd get a notice and it would assume the value to be "HELLO_WORLD" - same as if you'd typed:

```
$myVariable = "HELLO_WORLD";
```

Which would be error free.  Of course there are many reasons why you might want to define a constant.

Answer (score 3):

If constant Aahan is undefined it is treated as "Aahah" and send warning to you.

You should use ""

Comment: Does "constant" mean a number (integer/real)?

Comment: @Aahan, no constant may be a string http://ru.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php

Answer (score 2):

Use quotes when you want a string:

```
$string = "this is a string";
$numeric_string = "1"; //actually a string, but will act like an integer
$integer = 1; //an integer
$value_of_a_constant = foo; // If no constant named "foo" exists, 
                            // PHP assumes you meant a string containing "foo", 
                            // but emits a notice, see below
```

I recommend that you turn your error_reporting on (set to E_ALL, or E_STRICT), and turn display_errors on.  Do this at the very top of your script:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
```

If you had such a setup, you'd notice when you do `$var = Aahan`, PHP would output an error message (well, technically, a "notice"), telling you that you used an undefined constant, and it was treating it like a string.

Having E_ALL on while learning will help you learn better, faster.